# Trouble loading Python in RStudio with reticulate

Tags: python, r, rstudio, reticulate

I am trying to run a R Markdown document which uses both R and Python code chunks. I am on macOS Catalina version 10.15.2, R version is 3.6.2 and RStudio version is 1.2.5033. I am using the `reticulate` package version 1.14.

`which python` on the Terminal reveals `/Users/dhirajkhanna/opt/anaconda3/bin/python` and the same is entered in my `.Renviron` file as `RETICULATE_PYTHON=/Users/dhirajkhanna/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`. Strangely when I do `Sys.which('python')` in my RStudio console, it shows me a different path, viz. `/usr/bin/python`. When I load the `reticulate` package, the output of `py_config()` is:

```
python:         /usr/local/bin/python3
libpython:      /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-darwin/libpython3.7.dylib
pythonhome:     /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7:/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7
version:        3.7.4 (default, Jul  9 2019, 18:13:23)  [Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)]
numpy:          /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.16.4

python versions found: 
 /usr/bin/python3
 /usr/local/bin/python3
 /usr/bin/python
 /usr/local/bin/python
 /Users/dhirajkhanna/anaconda3/bin/python
 /Users/dhirajkhanna/.virtualenvs/object_recognition_detection/bin/python
 /Users/dhirajkhanna/.virtualenvs/object_recognition_detection1/bin/python
 /Users/dhirajkhanna/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/bin/python
 /Users/dhirajkhanna/venv/bin/python
```

If I specify, `use_python('/Users/dhirajkhanna/opt/anaconda3/bin/python')`, the output of `py_config()` is:

```
python:         /Users/dhirajkhanna/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
libpython:      /Users/dhirajkhanna/opt/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib
pythonhome:     /Users/dhirajkhanna/opt/anaconda3:/Users/dhirajkhanna/opt/anaconda3
version:        3.7.5 (default, Oct 25 2019, 10:52:18)  [Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]
numpy:          /Users/dhirajkhanna/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.17.3

python versions found: 
 /Users/dhirajkhanna/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
 /usr/bin/python3
 /usr/local/bin/python3
 /usr/bin/python
 /usr/local/bin/python
 /Users/dhirajkhanna/anaconda3/bin/python
 /Users/dhirajkhanna/.virtualenvs/object_recognition_detection/bin/python
 /Users/dhirajkhanna/.virtualenvs/object_recognition_detection1/bin/python
 /Users/dhirajkhanna/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/bin/python
 /Users/dhirajkhanna/venv/bin/python
```

Now when I try to load Python packages in a Python code chunk, RStudio crashes:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I get the "R Session Aborted" message. All this was working fine till I upgraded R. Any idea how to rectify this?

**Edit**

While trying this in R, I get a segmentation error:

```
> library(reticulate)
> repl_python()
Python 3.7.6 (/Users/dhirajkhanna/opt/anaconda3/bin/python)
Reticulate 1.14 REPL -- A Python interpreter in R.
>>> import pandas as pd

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x0, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: py_eval_impl(code, convert)
 2: py_eval("_", convert = FALSE)
 3: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 4: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 5: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 6: tryCatch(py_eval("_", convert = FALSE), error = function(e) r_to_py(NULL))
 7: py_last_value()
 8: py_compile_eval(code)
 9: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
10: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
11: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
12: tryCatch(py_compile_eval(code), error = handle_error)
13: repl()
14: repl_python()

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

I have also tried running a different version of Python (3.6) in a virtualenv but still no joy.

Comment: Does the python REPL work when you load `reticulate` and set `use_python` to your anaconda distribution? Just wondering if Python is loading at all into your RStudio. You can check the python REPL by typing `repl_python()` in your RStudio console, and typing `exit` to go back to the R prompt (see here: https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/)

Comment: @meenaparam I do get the python prompt, but as soon as I begin to type something, RStudio crashes.

Comment: Sounds like it's not the importing of packages causing a problem then. Sorry, I'm not sure about how to solve this. You could try posting an issue on GitHub. Your problem might also be related to this open issue: https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/456

Comment: @meenaparam thanks! Will give it a shot

Comment: In case it helps, RStudio crashes as soon as I insert a python code chunk in the RMarkdown file and start typing some code there. I don't have to execute the code chunk for RStudio to crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean install of `Rcpp` and `reticulate` solved the problem. More details [here](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/723).